# assign multiple element attributes with .each?

Tags: jquery, attributes, each

So I have the following table, and I'd like to set all the name attributes to a new value when I add a row to the table.  (You probably guessed it: I use the buttons to add and delete rows, and I calculate a new name attribute based on the row index).

```
<table id="orderstable" >
            <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="top"><img src="/images/images/add_button_sm.gif" id="add_" align="top" border="0">
                <img src="/images/images/delete_button_sm.gif" id="del_" border="0">
        </td>
        <td><input name="orderBoxes[0].A" size="3" value="0.0" type="text"></td>
        <td><input name="orderBoxes[0].B" size="3" value="0.0" type="text"></td>
        <td><input name="orderBoxes[0].C" size="3" value="0.0" type="text"></td>
        <td><select name="orderBoxes[0].D">
            <option value="fifty">50</option>
            <option value="oneHundred" selected="selected">100</option>
            <option value="twoHundred">200</option>
            <option value="threeHundred">300</option></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried to use .each to get all the  elements and then get at the input.name attribbute.... but I can't get it to work.  Any thoughts?  My code may not be the most efficient... I'm still a noob:

```
$("#orderstable > tbody > tr > td > img[id=add_]").click( function(event){
            var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
            var rowCopy=$(row).clone(true);
            $(row).closest("tbody").append(rowCopy);

            $('#orderstable tbody>tr:last>td').each(function(){
                            $(this.input).attr(name);
                            }).val = "test";
            row.className+="add_";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will grab the last row, and all input form elements. Then you can just set the `name` via `$(this).attr('name')`

```
$('#orderstable tr:last td :input').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('name', 'setyournamehere')
})
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks! SOrry I can't vote it up... not enough rep pts.

Comment: Given swatkins post above, why does the input here `('#orderstable tr:last td :input')` get all input elements, including select while the other post doesn't `$(e).find('input').attr('name')`?  Is

Comment: `find('input')` gets input elements by tag name. The pseudo selector `:input` Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector does not seem to be correct. Your table doesn't have the id 'orderstable' and does not have a `<tbody>`.

Comment: Yeh... I was trying to keep the post to a minimum.  I've added it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.each` function, you need to use the arguments to get at the element and find the input:

```
$("#orderstable > tbody > tr > td > img[id=add_]").click( function(event){
        var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
        var rowCopy=$(row).clone(true);
        $(row).closest("tbody").append(rowCopy);

        $('#orderstable tbody>tr:last>td :input').each(function(i, e){
                var n = $(e).attr('name');
            alert(n);
                        }).val = "test";
        row.className+="add_";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/swatkins/LFvwh/

Comment: Problem with this is that there's no input element in the first td so it's undefined, and the last td contains a select not an input. So finding an input would not work consistently.

Comment: Fair enough, it's an easy fix - add `:input` to the selector and remove the `find` method.