# Javascript setAttribute Vs jquery multiple attribute setter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set so many attributes for multiple elements. Javascript always give better performance when comparing to jquery.

i want to know which one gives better performance when settling multiple attributes via jquery and javascript.

**Jquery multiple attribute setter:**

```
$(element).attr({'id': 'id1', 'index':1, 'value':10,'check':'checked'});
```

**using javascript setAttribute :**

```
element.setAttribute('id','id1');
element.setAttribute('index','1');
..................................
```

when am using javascript i need to write multiple lines. otherwise need to create custom function for this.

can anyone explain which one gives better performance ?  and why ?

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: Unless you are talking about 100s of elements and 10s of properties, the cleaner `.attr()` way is the way to go.

Comment: @techfoobar am going to set more than 100 properties for more than 100 elements in a iteration.which one is best  and why ?

Comment: Why are you setting attributes when setting properties is likely faster and more appropriate?

Comment: Try it yourself: http://jsperf.com/.

Comment: A lot of those 100 properties i assume will be custom properties. It may be better to have one JS object containing all those and store it in one go using `.data()`. As for the HTML defined properties, vanilla will likely be faster since you have so many elements. Use http://jsperf.com to know the exact performance implications.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a jsperf which tests setting of attributes. I'm not sure that it covers your situation but as the others said - pure javascript is a lot faster then using a library. (I'm not even sure that the jsperf is a valid one. I mean if it test what you need).

http://jsperf.com/aaa-setting-attribute

jQuery version is 66% slower then the pure javascript variant.

Answer (score 1):

Computers cost much less than programmers.

Let's say:

Using pure js will make code run for 1ms, and programmer work 3 hours.

Using jQuery will make code run for 2ms and programmer work 1 minute

See *profit*?

Comment: Do you seriously think it would take 3 hours to do this with plan JS?

Comment: @RobG: depends on the programmer :)

Comment: Of course no :), just exaggregating. But imagine if you need to change smth in that code :)

Comment: @sergio–You are presuming that someone who can do the above with jQuery is so clueless as to be unable to write a simple function with 4 lines of code. As soon as the requirement goes beyond multiple properties for one element (e.g. multiple elements and multiple properties) then POJS becomes part of the solution anyway and the complexity and maintainability issues become virtually identical either way. The only difference is that a POJS solution doesn't required the programmer to also know jQuery.

Comment: Why would you ever assume the total value of time and resources wasted by executing a sub-optimal code to be lower than the time used to develop the code? I'm not saying the performance is what matters most, but if you may gain something with a relatively small cost (or no cost at all), then why not use it?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be setting properties, not attributes, as they are more consistent across browsers and have a more consistent effect on DOM elements (sometimes setting an attribute affects the property, sometimes it doesn't). Setting the property nearly always has the desired affect (e.g. setting a checkbox to checked), setting the related attribute doesn't always.

You can also use a small function if you want to set multiple properties on an element:

```
function setProperties(element, props) {
  for (var prop in props) {
    if (props.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      element[prop] = props[prop];
    }
  }
}
```

I can't see that it would be any slower than jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery is a library, so I think it better than pure javascript. It help you to use javascript easier. I supposed that!
You can see the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744175/assign-multiple-element-attributes-with-each)

If you want to get all of attributes of element, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645806/get-all-attributes-of-an-element-using-jquery) also.

Comment: Opinions should be expressed as comments, not answers.